# UIScroll View Extra Height and Ignoring Constraint

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have constraints set for 16 points under the scroll view, centered horizontally . Label is 16 points under the picture and centered horizontally. It looks good in interface builder. Once I run it, there is a huge amount of extra height in the scroll view. In interface builder the scroll view it lined up at the bottom of the nav bar and at the top of the tab bar. Why is it doing this? How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you center *anything* vertically?

Comment: @Luke The only constraints I set where the horizontal center for both and the 16 point top margin to scrollview and image view respectively. If I move the image under the nav bar it looks like it should but it looks weird in interface builder

Comment: then why do you expect it to be centered on the screen? The IB is not as tall as the actual phone.

Comment: Don't ever assume what looks good in the interface builder looks good in the device as well - they have entirely different dimensions.

Comment: what exactly? Do you want to center the label, then do it. But then there will be too much place above it. You are the designer, you have to choose what you want and then do it.

Comment: @luk2302 I want the running app to look like the interface builder above.

Comment: @luk2302 I need to know why the 16 point margin from the scrollview to the child and image view is more than 16 points. I think it has something to do with the size of the navigation bar but am completely lost as to why.

Comment: Can you show all the constraints in document outline of the IB?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the top and bottom to scroll view and connect between the elements to create a scroll if necessary, e.g.:

top of the scroll
     |
   image
     |
   label
     |
bottom of the scroll

try to put a bottom space constraint between your label and the scroll view and work with <= and = or you can use the UIStackView if your app is iOS 9+.